# Powershell script to install python and pip packages

Tags: powershell, pip

I'm trying to write a powershell script which will install Python and then proceed with pip package, conan, installation. The installation works successfully however the name conan is not recognized `The term 'conan' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet`.

```
Write-Host "Installing python"

Start-Process C:\CppBuildTools\Python\python-3.10.7-amd64.exe '/quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1' -wait

Write-Host "python installation completed successfully"

Write-Host "Reload environment variables"
$env:Path = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","Machine") + ";" + [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","User")
Write-Host "Reloaded environment variables"

Write-Host "Installing conan"

pip install conan

Write-Host "conan installation completed successfully"
```

This script installs Python for all users and adds it to the PATH. It seems everything is as expected so far, however when executing `pip install conan` there's already a strange log `Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable`. This log is not present when installing Python with GUI installer for all users and adding to Path option and then installing conan with `pip install conan`. Can someone help me understand what's the difference when using powershell script?

Comment: Are you running the script as Administrator?

Comment: No, but Python installation for all users I guess reuires Administrator right. Windows pop up window opens and asks for permission.

Comment: I have an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your
[Start-Process command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.2)
starts a new process that is separate from your script.

This means that it executes in parallel and is surely not finished
before you recompute the environment.

You should add the `-NoNewWindow` parameter to the command,
described as:

> **-NoNewWindow**
>
> Start the new process in the current console window. By default on
> Windows, PowerShell opens a new window. On non-Windows systems, you
> never get a new window.

Comment: Tried with `-NoNewWindow` parameter, the issue still exists, when installing conan the `Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable` log is there and after installation conan is again not recognized.

Comment: Have you run it as Administrator?

Comment: No, should I run it as administrator? I think in that case `pip install conan` will be called as administrator which is not advised.

Comment: I suggested it because of the message "normal site-packages is not writeable". It's interesting to do even as just a test.

Comment: Thanks again! Running as administrator worked. There's no "normal site-packages is not writeable" log and conan is a recognized name. Do you know why it fixed the issue?

Comment: Installers are normally executed as Admin, or they can't access some Windows stuff.

Comment: What I meant was that `pip install conan` is working with powershell without admin rights. Why this behavior changes when using powershell script?

Comment: Installing the python program requires Windows permissions. But after it's installed, it only installs packages to the python environment and not to Windows.

Comment: Thanks again for your help!